# Convert dateObj to toLocaleDateString in UI

Tags: momentjs

```
createDateTime: {date: 15, day: 1, hours: 12, minutes: 15, month: 5, nanos: 0, seconds: 30, time: 1592203530000,…}
date: 15
day: 1
hours: 12
minutes: 15
month: 5
nanos: 0
seconds: 30
time: 1592203530000
timezoneOffset: -330
year: 120
```

I was trying to convert above dateObj thought moment.js like below but it is not show the expected result:-
var x = moment(createDateTime).toDate().toLocaleDateString(navigator.language);
output : 1/6/120

expected ouput should be : 06/01/2020

Kindly help me to fix this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just use moment's parser by passing your input. It should give you expected result.

Here is the snippet

```js
let input = {
  createDateTime: {
    date: 15,
    day: 1,
    hours: 12,
    minutes: 15,
    month: 5,
    nanos: 0,
    seconds: 30,
    time: 1592203530000
  }
};

var dateString = moment(input.createDateTime).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
console.log(dateString);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's not fix my actual issue. Here you restrict to one format MM/DD/YYYY.
I have to use the browser toLocaleDateString(navigator.language) So user can select any date format like DD/MM/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY and YYYY/MM/DD.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you. the solution browser local worked for me.